# Using LINQ for an object that only has GetEnumerator()

Tags: .net, linq

Can you use LINQ in an object that exposes only Add(), Remove(), Count(), Item() and GetEnumerator() from System.Collections.IEnumerator?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The existing Linq extension methods work on objects that implement `IEnumerable<T>`. I assume your object implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface. In that case you can use the `Cast<T>` extension method to get a generic `IEnumerable<T>` wrapper. For instance, if the elements are of type `int` :

```
var wrapper = myObject.Cast<int>();
```

You can now use Linq on the wrapper

Answer (score 7):

Not directly. You could fairly easily write a `SingleShotEnumerable<T>` though:

```
 public sealed class SingleShotEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
 {
     private IEnumerator<T> enumerator;

     public SingleShotEnumerable(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
     {
         if (enumerator == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerator");
         }
         this.enumerator = enumerator;
     }

     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
     {
         if (enumerator == null)
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException
                 ("GetEnumerator can only be called once");
         }
         var ret = enumerator;
         enumerator = null;
         return ret;
     }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
         return GetEnumerator();
     }
 }
```

This is assuming you *actually* have an `IEnumerator<T>`. If you just have `IEnumerator`, you could write something similar only implementing `IEnumerable`, then use `Cast` or `OfType` to get to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

(Note: this isn't thread-safe. You could make it so with locks if you really wanted.)

You could then do:

```
 var filtered = from person in new SingleShotEnumerable<Person>(personEnumerator)
                where person.Age > 18
                select person.Name;
```

... but you couldn't use the query twice.

How have you got into the strange situation of only having an `IEnumerator<T>` anyway? That's quite rare. See if you can design your way around that to avoid having to do something like the above, which is quite fragile.

(An alternative would be to "drain" the `IEnumerator<T>` to a `List<T>` or something similar, but that has problems dealing with large or potentially *infinite* sequences.)

Comment: Some `System.Windows.Forms` types, such as `ListViewItemCollection`, don't seem to implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @ChrisAkridge: Indeed, they only implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`. But you can always call `Cast<>` to create an `IEnumerable<T>` from it.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. All LINQ methods are extensions methods for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

So you'll have to implement `IEnumerable<T>` to use LINQ with your own collections.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper class:

```
namespace System.Linq {
  public sealed class EnumerableWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    readonly IEnumerator<T> Enumerator;
    public EnumerableWrapper(IEnumerator<T> enumerator) => Enumerator = enumerator;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => Enumerator;
    Collections.IEnumerator Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Then use Linq on a new instance of `EnumerableWrapper`