# Find Small Number in Matrix

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a matrix like this

```
13   7   22

101  50  3
```

I Want to Print The smallest Number from the same.
Below is my Code:

```
using System;
class Class1
{    int min(int[,] arr)
    {
        int small = arr[0, 0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (small > arr[i, j])
                {
                    small = arr[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
        return small;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] x;
        x = new int[,] { { 13, 7, 22 }, { 101, 50, 3 } };

        Class1 obj = new Class1();        
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest Element : {0}", obj.min(x));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Throws Error as

> {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}

**Expected output is 3**

Why am getting this error? Please give me solution.

Comment: Your array has 2 rows and three columns.Outer for loop is to traverse through row and inner loop is for columns. So logically your outer loop condition should be i<2.Happy Coding.. Up vote if you find comments & answer helpful.

Comment: thanks @Pavan .. yes

Comment: I sence lack of debugging work.. If you had tried, you would know it by yourself.

Comment: You already have the answer, but I just want to point out that you can use Linq to find the minimum value like so: `int min = x.Cast<int>().Min();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is `2X3` so you have specify condition for first loop is `i<2`

Like this

```
int min(int[,] arr)
        {
            int small = arr[0, 0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (small > arr[i, j])
                    {
                        small = arr[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return small;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Worked for me.

Comment: What if the next array would be 4%5? Better use the `GetLength` method.

Comment: IT's hard coded in code.In case of user input it will break

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can use `foreach` to iterate over all the elements of a multidimensional array without having to worry about indices.

So it is simpler to write your `min()` method like so (note that I'm also using `Math.Min()` to find the lower of two values rather than writing my own `if` to do it):

```
static int min(int[,] arr)
{
    int small = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (int n in arr)
        small = Math.Min(n, small);

    return small;
}
```

Also note how I initialised `small` to be the largest possible int, in order to avoid having to access the first value of the array to initialise it.

If you wanted to use Linq to do the same thing you can just do this:

```
int min = array.Cast<int>().Min();
```

The reason that `Cast<int>` is needed is because a multidimensional array only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` rather than the generic `IEnumerable<T>`. [See this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415777/using-linq-for-an-object-that-only-has-getenumerator).

However using Linq an advanced topic if you are currently learning C#, in which case don't worry about that for now!

Comment: Thanks @matthew this Linq method seem fine and very easy one line code.

Comment: Yes... Good solution... `int min = array.Cast<int>().Min();`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code, it will resolve `X x X` matrix

```
List<List<int>> matrix = new List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>()
    {
        new List<int>() {5,10,6}, new List<int>() {6,11,7}, new List<int>() {7,12,8}, new List<int>() {8,13,9}
    };
```

To find MIN Value:

```
matrix.SelectMany(m => m.Select(n => n)).OrderBy(m => m).FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

To find MAX Value

```
matrix.SelectMany(m => m.Select(n => n)).OrderByDescending(m => m).FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

If you are using multi dimensional **`array`**

```
int[,] matrix = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };

IEnumerable<int> query = matrix.OfType<int>();

query.SelectMany(m => m.Select(n => n)).OrderBy(m => m).FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```